# Flask context error when trying to serve a tensorflow model

Tags: python, flask

I have a simple flask app to serve a tensorflow model. As far as I am aware, I have ironed out all of the other errors. But when it comes time to run the app I get this error:

```
RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 61, in <module>
    if request.args:
  File "/home/m0oN/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", 
line 347, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "/home/m0oN/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", 
line 306, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "/home/m0oN/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/globals.py", 
line 37, in _lookup_req_object
    raise RuntimeError(_request_ctx_err_msg)
RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem.
```

I think the main problem lies in here:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    file_name = 'steph.jpg'
    model_file = 'thotornot_graph.pb'
    lable_file = 'retrained_labels.txt'
    input_height = 299
    input_width = 299
    input_mean = 128
    input_std = 128
    input_layer = "Mul"
    output_layer = "final_result"

    if request.args:
        file_name = request.args

    graph = load_graph(model_file)
    t = read_tensor_from_image_file(file_name,
                                input_height=input_height,
                                input_width=input_width,
                                input_mean=input_mean,
                                input_std=input_std)

    input_name = 'import/' + input_layer
    output_name = 'import/' + output_layer
    input_operation = graph.get_operation_by_name(input_name);
    output_operation = graph.get_operation_by_name(output_name);

    with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
        start = time.time()
        results = sess.run(output_operation.outputs[0],
                        {input_operation.outputs[0]: t})
        end = time.time()
    results = np.squeeze(results)

    top_k = results.argsort()[-5:][::-1]
    lables = load_lables(lable_file)

    print('\nEvaluation time (1-image): {:.3f}s\n'.format(end-start))

    for i in top_k:
        print(lables[i], results[i])

app.run(localhost, 8081)
```

A link to my code full is here https://paste.ee/p/ztYKg

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow ! You should get a look on how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on this site. For instance, your code should not be in a third party website, but stripped down to it's core and embedded in the question.

Comment: @Lescurel would this me more suitable?

Comment: You should embed the Traceback too (In plain text, not an image). I'll add that I don't think that the tensorflow tag is relevant here, you clearly have a Flask problem.

Comment: Are you sure you understand what Flask is for? What are you trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: @jwg I am probably not as educated as I should be in the field of flask but to my knowledge, it is a web serving microframework, if another module or framework would do this better please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The line that is causing the error:

```
if request.args:
    file_name = request.args
```

doesn't seem to have any purpose here. You're not servicing a request, why are you trying to retrieve the request args? `request` is a Flask helper which will give information about a web request, **when** called from inside endpoint code. It will not work anywhere else.

Comment: The code ran successfully but I couldn't send a request to the server which is the main point of the code, Thanks for the help though.